# Android Error SQLiteStatement create table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table with four foreign keys with two of these pointing at the same table. When I launched the activity for the first time, I notified an error in logcat, but I cannot find any sort of error. Thanks for the help

This is my table statemnt

```
public static final String TRANSACTION_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_TYPE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_ACCOUNT_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_TRANSFER_ACCOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_BUDGET_ID + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_HOLDER + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " REAL, "
        + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " REAL, "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_ACCOUNT_ID + ") REFERENCES " + AccountTable.ACCOUNT_TABLE_NAME + " (" + AccountTable.COLUMN_ID + "), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + ") REFERENCES " + CategoryTable.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME + " (" + CategoryTable.COLUMN_ID + "), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_TRANSFER_ACCOUNT + ") REFERENCES " + AccountTable.ACCOUNT_TABLE_NAME + " (" + AccountTable.COLUMN_ID + "), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_BUDGET_ID + ") REFERENCES " + BudgetTable.BUDGET_TABLE_NAME + " (" + BudgetTable.COLUMN_ID + ")"
        + ");";
```

This is my logcat

```
>08-02 15:06:06.854    1110-1110/it.kage.crusoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.kage.crusoe/it.kage.crusoe.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "transaction": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT, type INTEGER NOT NULL, amount REAL NOT NULL, status INTEGER NOT NULL, account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, transfer_account INTEGER NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, register_date TEXT NOT NULL, budget_id INTEGER, holder TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (_id), FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (_id), FOREIGN KEY (transfer_account) REFERENCES account (_id), FOREIGN KEY (budget_id) REFERENCES budget (_id));
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "transaction": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT, type INTEGER NOT NULL, amount REAL NOT NULL, status INTEGER NOT NULL, account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, transfer_account INTEGER NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, register_date TEXT NOT NULL, budget_id INTEGER, holder TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (_id), FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (_id), FOREIGN KEY (transfer_account) REFERENCES account (_id), FOREIGN KEY (budget_id) REFERENCES budget (_id));
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
        at it.kage.crusoe.database.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:42)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
        at it.kage.crusoe.database.adapters.DatabaseAdapter.open(DatabaseAdapter.java:34)
        at it.kage.crusoe.database.adapters.DatabaseAdapter.<init>(DatabaseAdapter.java:26)
        at it.kage.crusoe.database.adapters.AccountAdapter.<init>(AccountAdapter.java:33)
        at it.kage.crusoe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Transaction" is a [reserved word](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite. You'll need to pick a different name or quote the identifier in double quotes or brackets. It's recommended that you quote all identifiers (if they're English words) so that your code doesn't break if the word is added as a reserved keyword in the future.

Comment: you do not need to pick a different one check this: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: @Michelle..Super bro...you saved my day..Thanks +1 vote